# C Pre-Processor Conditional Directive Precedence and Nesting

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have some code that has an existing preprocessor conditional directives of the form:

```
#ifndef SYMBOL_XYZ
// some code here
#else
// some other code here
#endif
```

and I want to add a new condition that supersedes that logic, and I think this is the way to do it but I'm unsure of the subtleties around nesting and precedence when it comes to the C pre-processor.

```
#ifdef NEW_SYMBOL_ABC
// some new code here that takes precedence over the other two conditions
#else
   #ifndef SYMBOL_XYZ
   // some code here
   #else
   // some other code here
   #endif
#endif
```

Do I have that right? Would it be equivalent to do:

```
#ifndef NEW_SYMBOL_ABC
   #ifndef SYMBOL_XYZ
   // some code here
   #else
   // some other code here
   #endif
#else
   // some new code here that takes precedence over the other two conditions
#endif
```

Comment: It is called pre-processor

Comment: it's ok.
If you check the gcc header files, you will find a lot of preprocessor nesting like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .. .

```
#ifdef NEW_SYMBOL_ABC
// some new code here that takes precedence over the other two conditions
#elif  !defined(SYMBOL_XYZ)
// some code here
#else
// some other code here 
#endif
```

Above is what I commonly use and should work with gcc for sure.
Not sure, but should work with visual c++ and other compilers.

Comment: Yes, this is standard and portable. And, it's worth mentioning that it's equivalent to the code in the question, which is also already correct.